# Creating customers programatically issue

Tags: magento-1, customer, multistore, customer-account

I want to create some **customers programatically** and I have an issue when I want to save the website ID.

I have multiple website IDs:

```
0 => admin
1 => germany
2 => hungary
3 => romania
```

This is my code:

```
 $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
 $customer->setWebsiteId(3);
 $customer->setStoreId(1);
.....
 $customer->save();
```

When I saved a customer I get the `Admin` value selected from the **website drop down**. Whatever value I give to the website Id (like `12321`) I got the `Admin` value. Why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the sample of my code and you have to set the website ID 2 times. Don't ask me why. Maybe someone will give you a better solution but this one is works for me:

```
 $customer->setWebsiteId(1);
 $customer->setStoreId(5);
 $customer->setData(.....)

 $customer->save();

 $customer->setConfirmation(null);
 $customer->setWebsiteId(1); 
 $customer->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this code:

```
//If you know store id
$storeId = 'id';
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId); // Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
if($store && $store->getId()) {
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setStore($store);
}


//->setStore reference:app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
/**
 * Set store to customer
 *
 * @param Mage_Core_Model_Store $store
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
 */
public function setStore(Mage_Core_Model_Store $store)
{
    $this->setStoreId($store->getId());
    $this->setWebsiteId($store->getWebsite()->getId());
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I get this error message:  Fatal error:  Uncaught Mage_Core_Exception: Customer website ID must be specified when using the website scope

Comment: You're trying load customer by Email? This problem is referred in: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Resource/Customer.php:212 +0- Please read: http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/programmaticaly-adding-new-customers-to-the-magento-store/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$websitesArray = array(0 => "admin",
                1 => "germany",
                2 => "hungary",
                3 => "romania");
foreach($websitesArray as $websiteId => $websiteName) {
    $website = Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId);
    if($website->getId()) {
        $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
        $customer->setWebsiteId($website->getId())
                    ->setFirstname('John')
                    ->setLastname('Doe')
                    ->setEmail('jd1@ex.com')
                    ->setPassword('somepassword');

        try{
            $customer->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
        }       
    }
}
```

**Note :**

Go to admin side `System > configuration > Customers  > Customer Configuration > Account Sharing Options` and set `Per Website` in field `Share Customer Accounts`